# Updating attribute on get request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where I would like to update an attribute when a certain third party fetches data from my api's endpoint.

Currently, I've set this up as follows

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ListingsController < ApplicationController    
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "third_party_user", password: "secret", except: :index
    before_action :update_status, only: [:publishable_listings]
    def publishable_listings
     @listings = Listings.where(to_publish: true)
    end 

    private

    def update_status
     listings = Listings.where(to_publish: true).update_all(published: true)
    end 
  end
 end
end
```

and this is just the route

```
...
get 'publishable_listings' => "listings#publishable_listings"
...
```

Is this considered bad practice or could there be an alternative way to accomplish this?

Basically, this assumes that the only `GET` requests coming to publishable_listings would be from `third_party_user` and if anyone else would be able to make a `GET` this would be problematic since it would update the record without actually being published.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question would fit better into https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/ruby.

> Is this considered bad practice or could there be an alternative way to accomplish this?

> Basically, this assumes that the only GET requests coming to publishable_listings would be from third_party_user and if anyone else would be able to make a GET this would be problematic since it would update the record without actually being published.

With your current architecture using basic auth, I don't see a different way of implementing this. Assuming that only your third party will ever know the password, this might be fine.

However, if you would introduce a concept of user, you would be able to only mark publishing for a user as published / read. You could implement this with a many to many relationship.

Another way of implementing this could be to just use curser based pagination and store the latest cursor in your client. This way, your client could go back and it's easier to debug and reason about.

https://slack.engineering/evolving-api-pagination-at-slack/

A few more suggestions

To keep your controller simple, you should only have the basic REST methods in your controller (index, show, new, create, edit, update, delete). In your case, you could have a `PublishableListingsController` with a `show` method instead of `ListingsController` with a `publishable_listings`.

See this great article for more details http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/.

Also the assignment to `listings` here is not really used and I would recommend to do this not an a before action, because, if your second query fails, you will end up with listing which are already marked published but where never actually received.

```rb
def update_status
  listings = Listings.where(to_publish: true).update_all(published: true)
end
```

Ideally you want to do this in one operation or transaction.

```rb
def show
  @listings = Listings.where(to_publish: true)
  @listing.update_all(published: true)
end
```